# Typo3 8.7: Name of module is not displayed in backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my Typo3 8.7 extension I register a module for the backend. The module itself works fine unfortunately the name is not displayed. (The name in the list on the left side in the module menu).

I have read the doku and did everything what is says there. I have reactivated the extension multiple times and deleted all cache (install cache aswell). 
Here is my code in the `ext_tables.php`:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
call_user_func(
    function ($extKey) {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
            'TYPO3.' . $extKey,   
            'Customer Administration',      
            'Customer Administration',          
            '',                    
            array(                  
                'BackendManagement' => 'list,  membershipInformationBackend',
                'FrontendManageCertificate' => 'showCertificateDetails'
            ),
            array(                 
                'access' => 'user,group',
                'icon' => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/ext_icon_small.svg',
                'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_shop_backend.xlf',
            )
        );

    },
    $_EXTKEY
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'someExt');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('tx_someExt_domain_model_backendcustomer', 'EXT:someExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_tx_someExt_domain_model_backendcustomer.xlf');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_someExt_domain_model_backendcustomer');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come on my friend, There is only a single mistake I found in your code. You have not passed the key of the translation file. This is the possible issue, please check the below solution:

**ext_tables.php**

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
call_user_func(
    function ($extKey) {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
            'TYPO3.' . $extKey,   
            'Customer Administration',      
            'Customer Administration',          
            '',                    
            array(                  
                'BackendManagement' => 'list,  membershipInformationBackend',
                'FrontendManageCertificate' => 'showCertificateDetails'
            ),
            array(                 
                'access' => 'user,group',
                'icon' => 'EXT:' . $extKey . '/ext_icon_small.svg',
                'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $extKey . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_shop_backend.xlf:shopModule', // Here is the problem
            )
        );

    },
    $_EXTKEY
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'someExt');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('tx_someExt_domain_model_backendcustomer', 'EXT:someExt/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_tx_someExt_domain_model_backendcustomer.xlf');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_someExt_domain_model_backendcustomer');
}
```

**locallang_shop_backend.xlf**

```
<trans-unit id="shopModule">
    <source>Shop Management</source>
</trans-unit>
```

**Suggestion:** If you have created an extension using extension builder, there is one auto-generated file named **locallang_db.xlf** use this file for backend labeling.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Thank you, you were completely right! Don't know how I missed the key there though.. ;)